# Laravel push notification desktop (chome or firefox)

Tags: laravel, notifications, push

It is possible to implement push notifications desktop (chrome or firefox) for each specific user application using https://github.com/developerdynamo/laravel-push-notification?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. As long as you have a way sync with the client in the background, like a websocket connecion, you can easily use the [Web Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification).